# Traffic lights simulation: change the color of the traffic light

Tags: c#

I am working on a traffic lights simulation and right now I am trying to make the traffic lights switch the color (both car and pedestrian traffic lights). The issue is that I have 8 traffic lights per intersection and 12 intersections. I've tried with a timer and a counter but the problem is that the interval is not respected:

If the starting color is red, the red time is 8 and the green time is 10 then when the color will become green, in two seconds it will be changed back to red.
Here's the timer code:

```
private void timerTrafficLights_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;

    foreach(TrafficLight t in trafficLights)
    {
        if(counter%t.RedTime==0 &&t.TrafficColor==TrafficLightColor.RED)
        {
            t.SwitchLight(t, TrafficLightColor.GREEN, t.ID);
        }
        else if(counter % t.GreenTime==0 && t.TrafficColor==TrafficLightColor.GREEN)
        {
            t.SwitchLight(t, TrafficLightColor.RED, t.ID);
        }
    }

    foreach(PedestrianLight p in pedestrianLights)
    {
        if(counter % p.RedTime==0 && p.LightColor == PedestrianLightColor.RED)
        {
            p.SwitchLight(p, p.ID, PedestrianLightColor.GREEN);
        }
        else if (counter % p.GreenTime ==0 && p.LightColor == PedestrianLightColor.GREEN)
        {
            p.SwitchLight(p, p.ID, PedestrianLightColor.RED);
        }
    }

    UI.InvalidateEvent.InvalidatePanel();
}

private void TimerTrafficLights()
{
    timerTrafficLights.Interval = 1000;
    timerTrafficLights.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTrafficLights_Tick);
    timerTrafficLights.Start();
}
```

The timer is started when the simulation starts and the value of the counter at the beginning of the simulation is 0.

Comment: Keep two counters for red and green light

Comment: That would work if I'd have only one traffic light or if they all have the same green or red time.. which they don't.

Comment: Dispatcher runs on a timer.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx  Maybe up the priority and run it faster.   WPF is not the right tool for a visual simulation like this.

Comment: I wrote a poker game in WPF trying to get visuals to synch up is pretty much impossible.  It is just not what WPF is built to do.  It does *minimal* screen paints for speed and scale.  Look for a game development environment.

Comment: I did not choose to do it like this.. It is a school project.

Comment: From a point of view of an Object Oriented approach to this problem I would leave the job of changing color to the TrafficLight and PedestrianLight classes

Comment: The color is changed inside the class but the method has to be called somehow, right? I mean, I could do it more loosely coupled but my priority is to have it as close to real time traffic light switching.

Comment: see the complete implementation here: https://github.com/gmershad/TrafficLightSystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this task from an Object Oriented way. It is not your Timer that changes the color of your TrafficLight (and PedestrianLight) but it is the class itself that knows when it is time to change color.

In this scenario your TrafficLight class could be something like this

```
// I show just the TrafficLight class, but the same is true for the 
// PedestrianLight class (better if both derives from the same base class)
public class TrafficLight
{
    private int counter = 0;
    public TrafficLightColor TrafficColor { get; set; }
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int RedTime { get; set; }
    public int GreenTime { get; set; }

    public void SwitchLight(TrafficLightColor color)
    {
        if(color != TrafficColor)
        {
            TrafficColor = color;
            // Restart the counter everytime the color changes.....
            // So the next change happens for the current color.
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    public void Tick()
    {
        if (this.TrafficColor == TrafficLightColor.RED && counter == RedTime)
             SwitchLight(TrafficLightColor.GREEN);
        else if ((this.TrafficColor == TrafficLightColor.GREEN && counter == GreenTime)
             SwitchLight(TrafficLightColor.RED);
    }
}
```

And now, the Timer Tick event just calls for each instance of the TrafficLight (and PedestrianLight) the Tick method.

```
private void timerTrafficLights_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(TrafficLight t in trafficLights)
       t.Tick();

    foreach(PedestrianLight p in pedestrianLights)
       p.Tick();

    UI.InvalidateEvent.InvalidatePanel();
}
```

In this way you don't need to keep an external counter of ticks outside the class. Each instance knows its boundaries and changes the color when time is right. You can even have TrafficLights with different timing for Red and Green lights because all the logic of changing color is contained in the instance itself that works with its own settings for Red and Green

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to the traffic/pedestrian Light class

```
public int startTime;
```

With this you only need to store the start time. At each tick you will check if the difference is bigger than the threshold. After change, reset the time to the current.

Comment: Not so sure I understood completely. I addws that as a property and in the timer Im checking the following:  if(counter- t.currentTime==t.RedTime &&t.TrafficColor==TrafficLightColor.RED)
                {
                    t.SwitchLight(t, TrafficLightColor.GREEN, t.ID);
                    t.currentTime = counter;
                }
                else if(counter - t.currentTime == t.GreenTime && t.TrafficColor==TrafficLightColor.GREEN)
                {
                    t.SwitchLight(t, TrafficLightColor.RED, t.ID);
                    t.currentTime = counter;
                }

Comment: That's what i was thinking.

Comment: Now thats not working cause if the counter will be equal to the currentTime=> change. But in that case its gonna compare it to the red time. It has to be equal to 0 and when the statement is true the counter has to be set to 0 again. Gonna try and come back with a reply.